# Multiple AVPlayer synchronous playback

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I have 3 `AVPlayer` instances on a single `UIView`. All 3 `AVPlayers` receive 3 streams of the same length from the network. I want all the 3 players to start simultaneously.

What would be best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If all the players have already been created and configured in the UIView, why not just create a function that calls the play method for all three players.

```
  -(void)playAll{
    [avPlayer1 play];
    [avPlayer2 play];
    [avPlayer3 play];
  }
```